# Google Experiments: testing variants on dual-language page

Tags: google-analytics

I need to set up A/B testing for my **homepage** using Google Experiments. Thing is, my page serves 2 languages - English and German.

The path to homepage itself is simply `/` for EN, and `/de` for DE.

Then, I have the following variations of the homepage prepared:

- /experiment-A **and** /de/experiment-A
- /experiment-B **and** /de/experiment-B

The goal for the experiment is user's registration. I don't care which language the user has set. The **question is**: Do I need to set up 2 separate experiments for the two language versions?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I'd set up two experiments. The plus side is you'll also be able to get some insights from it. I find Germans behave quite differently than our North American visitors.